# Do I have to use google In-App purchases if I sell a physical good that also unlocks access to our app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment, google-pay

**Situation:**

We want to sell our app along with a physical device. Thus we don't know if we have to use Google In-App purchases, because it unlocks access to our software (must be used with In-App purchases) and also sells a physical good. (does not have to be sold with in-App purchases)

**edit**

It seems that I have not described our situation accurately enough.
We want to sell the physical device and the access to our app as a fixed bundle. Our app is supposed to enhance security when you are driving, but it requires a smartphone-holder. We are not planning to produce the holder ourself because there are far more experienced manufacturers. Thus we will only buy and resell the holder with an access code for our software. 
In the end the question is, if we are allowed to use external payment methods, where we don't need to pay 30% commission.

**guidelines**

Google only states the following in their guidelines:

Developers offering additional content, services or functionality within another category of app downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment, except: >

where payment is primarily for physical goods or services (e.g., buying movie tickets, or buying a publication where the price also includes a hard copy subscription);

While apple states clearly, how a situaion like this must be handled, Google does not. Or am I wrong? Can somebody help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like it belongs more on [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You don't clearly explain your situation. "You want to sell your app?" Ok that doesn't need IAP. "You unlock software [in the app]" ok that should use IAP. If you sell physical goods, then that doesn't _have_ to use IAP. If you are selling both as a bundle, then you need to determine "primary focus" and you haven't give us enough detail to decide. _Hint_ it should be up to your company to decide and hold that position if you have valid reasoning - i.e. no wrong answer.

Comment: @Blundell Thanks, your answer already helped. I tried to explain our situation more accurate this time. Do you think it would be accepted if we set our primary focus on the hardware?

Comment: Yes I believe that is a genuine use case, the primary sale is the phone holder